# Python list max element allowed

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am reading file and putting all the data of file in `list`. file size is quite big  about 80k records. In `python` is good practice to store these number of data in `list`?

Later i am splitting this list and building the request to send to API.

here is example

```
content_list = []
    with open("file") as reader:
        for line in reader:
            content_list .append(line)
```

Comment: Is it slow? Taking up too much memory? Are you afraid of losing any changes if the program has to restart while it has a list in memory? If none of those are concerns, and there aren't any other concerns, I don't see why not. Although you could just do `content_list = reader.readlines()` which would be a lot simpler than the loop you have.

Comment: "file size is quite big about 80k records." That is *tiny*.

Answer (score 0):

the object has `readlines` method as default

```
with open("file") as f:
        content_list = f.readlines()
        #or
        #content_list = list(f)
```

Comment: You can even convert the open file directly into a list: `with open("file") as f: content_list = list(f)`.

Comment: You should use `list(f)` `readlines` is a holdover from a more primitive API, before the file-object was an iterator